# How to catch c3p0 and JPA exceptions?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I got this app where the user must connect the DB manually, I do that with this line

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit", connectionProperties);
```

when the user/password is incorrect or the host timeouts due to wrong url C3P0 breaks the connection

then I get these in console

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask, 1853 - A RESOURCE POOL IS PERMANENTLY BROKEN! [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@18e3f02a]
```

THE PROBLEM: I can't capture that exception so I can translate it to a user friendly message on screen, it is like emf is always created and I got no way to tell when is broken or not

UPDATE: I found on Hibernate http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-exceptions

But I surrounded my emf with EVERY single try catch possible and still can't catch a thing

Comment: can someone confirm my question is understandable? I can't believe no one found themselves on this case before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JPA spec says that *Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory* will return null if a persistence-unit can't be instantiated (and states nothing about possible exceptions). Consequently it's as much use as a chocolate teapot for detecting the reason programmatically. Complain to the people who wrote the JPA spec.

Comment: wish it was returning null, because I could catch a null pointer exception, but is not, it returns an active, open entitymanager that points to a broken resource...

Comment: You mean EntityManagerFactory, not EntityManager, yes? DataNucleus JPA throws PersistenceException in your particular situation actually, so is detectable.

Comment: ye I meant emf, ok I'll have a look at DataNucleus

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread.

But I was trying to do exactly the same as you.
I did a big search and could not find the answer, even you posted this a long time ago and got no answer.

Well.. what happens is that most Hibernate code catches exceptions and put it into a local exception list.

For example, take a look at `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute()` where it catches all jdbc exceptions and put them on exceptions list.
Unfortunately, the code that uses this class lose track of these exceptions since the objects are not referenced anymore.

All exceptions are logged though.. but I find this behavior really annoying since I'm a control freak. The idea of putting exceptions on a list is very good for a framework. But if the other end can't use it.. it's just code bloat and it makes you wast time analyzing why you can't get the God damn exception (For those who never give up).

What I do is perform some basic start up operations on the database and when I get a query exception, then I know something is wrong. The error page in the servlet is more generic but doesn't give the user the impression that the system has lots of bugs (hehe, this sounded wrong).

Ah.. just a remark. It's not a JPA specification problem (like DataNucleus said) since if you use hibernate's native initialization, it's the same. Although I really think JPA lacks of initialization exceptions.

Comment: That is a lot of text, can you bold the actual answer maybe? :)

Comment: Not really an answer.. just a small explanation of why **you can't actually do** what @javaNoober was trying to do... in this case specifically with Hibernate. But you are right.. I should have tried to highlight the answer even though there is already one elected.